# Web folder gets deleted when uploading a large image in CKeditor 5

Tags: wysiwyg, 10

I'm getting the strangest and most annoying behaviour when trying to upload an image bigger than the php `upload_max_filesize` setting: it fails, but also completely deletes the `web` directory (the document root)!

Images smaller than `upload_max_filesize` don't trigger this mess.
After adjusting the value of `upload_max_filesize`, uploading an image that did trigger it now works.

To make this even more interesting, this only happens on the production and staging server, not my local machine, even though the php version is roughly the same.

Here are details on my setup:

- drupal 10.1.6
- php-fpm 8.2.10
- apache 2.4.52

Nothing in the PHP nor apache logs. In Drupal watchdog message, the only (semi)relevant message is:

> The file permissions could not be set on public://inline-images/la-haute-societe-1_1.jpg.

on the `/ckeditor5/upload-image/free_content` URL (this is indeed the image I tried to upload).

Any one already faced this issue? Any pointer when to start debugging this?

Comment: Have you read over the Drupal, PHP, and server logs in great detail?

Comment: I forgot to mention it but of course I did. I edited the question with the few info I got.

Comment: I've never heard anything like this. It is extraordinary. Is there a sysadmin on that hosting platform you could consult with?

Comment: Yep there is but he decided it's not his problem since it looks like the big is in the app.

Comment: Just an idea: to rule out the involvement of CKEditor, what do you experience when uploading the same over-quota-sized file into a good-old plain File field on a Node content, let's say?